# $.ajax timeout example wrong and hazardous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When searched for "long-polling using jquery", this [link](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) is the top result and I'm surprised why people haven't cared to know if they were correct about what they said.

### They say:

> Timeout: Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. The timeout
>   period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made. Here, we set the
>   timeout to 30 seconds. This means our poll function won't get called
>   again until both the ajax call is complete and **(at-least) thirty (30)**
>   **seconds have passed**.

(emphasis mine)

But that is not the case, I suppose.

I tested this code:

```
(function foo(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/echo/json',
        success:function(d){
          console.log('Logged after 30secs');
        },
        timeout:30000,
        complete: foo
    });
})();
```

and here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43df3/) to prove that the emphasized text is wrong.

You can see that `console.log()` is getting called before 30 seconds.

> Both the `setTimeout` and `setInterval` techniques suffer from same flaw - a new
>   connection to the server must be opened each time the `$.ajax` method
>   is called. To make that connection, your realtime app must gear up and
>   battle through hoards of competing network traffic to make it to your
>   server.

### Is there any reliable solution(except sockets) to make long-polling flawless?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are wrong. The timeout, as i understand it, specifies the maximum amount of time the xmlhttprequest will spend to try to get the information from the server.

Comment: "Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override any global timeout set with$.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made" - jQuery docs, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Can you please clarify what "it" is in your "make it flawless" question? Timeout indeed specifies max time, not min time, but it is clear from documentation. If you need to guarantee some time between calls just wait after call completion if needed...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov edited to be more clear

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are looking for - if *your* case requires particular behavior - implement it (i.e. sometimes you just need on response as soon as it is available). Default implementation of long-poll is to queue request as soon as previous is complete so you always getting data from server as soon as it is available. Note that if server replies *immediately* to request you'll need to wait between calls, but I'd not call it long-poll.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov to explain a bit more, I'm currently using setTimeout + recursive function pattern for checking if a file is present in the server. I'm afraid it is making my site slow. So, thought I must try long-polling as it reduces the payload. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Long-poll requires significant change in server side code and type of communication (i.e. "is file there" vs. "let me know when file shows up") - I have no idea what you have and unlikly will be able to help. Side note: "I'm afraid it is making my site slow"  is very strange statement - it is your site and your should be able to measure performance, decide if it is "slow" or not, and than pinpoint what piece of code causes slowness if needed. Consider asking new more specific questions after you sorted out what is slow.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you're right. But I'm not that good in Unit testing. BTW, its "let me know when the file shows up". Will code review my code behind.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov check this if you review code http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55584/speed-up-responding-time-in-a-ashx-handler-while-searching-for-a-file

Answer (score 2):

Hang on, the timeout option with jQuery's ajax method has nothing to do with long polling. The article about long polling is right. It used setTimeout in a closure. Because the next execution of the function is inside the function it self, it guarantees that the function is called one after one at a time.

The jQuery $.ajax's timeout option, however, allows specifying a time after which the call is canceled. i.e. if the server take too long to response, simply cancel the request. It has nothing to do with 'long polling'.

The block of code should be:

```
(function foo(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       $.ajax({
          url:'/echo/json',
          success:function(d){
            console.log('Logged after 30secs');
            foo()
          }
       });
    }, 30000);


})();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I usted this code:
>
> ```
> (function foo(){
>     $.ajax({
>         url:'/echo/json',
>         success:function(d){
>           console.log('Logged after 30secs');
>         },
>         timeout:30000,
>         complete: foo
>     });
> })();
> ```
>
> they say: *the poll function won't get called again until both the
>   ajax call is complete and (at-least) thirty (30) seconds have passed.*

That is indeed [very wrong](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). It should be: "*the poll function will get called as soon as either the ajax call is complete or (at most) thirty (30) seconds have passed*" for your code.

However, notice that neither this code nor that statement can be found on [their website](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery). They use a code that is very different from yours:

> ```
> (function poll() {
>    setTimeout(function() {
>        $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data) {
>             sales.setValue(data.value);
>        }, dataType: "json", complete: poll });
>     }, 30000);
> })();
> ```

Here the `poll` function will get called again as soon as thirty seconds have passed and then the ajax call is completed.

> > Both the setTimeout and setInterval techniques suffer from same flaw -
> >     a new connection to the server must be opened each time the `$.ajax`
> >     method is called. To make that connection, your realtime app must gear
> >     up and battle through hoards of competing network traffic to make it
> >     to your server.
>
> Is there any reliable solution (except sockets) to make long-polling flawless?

Well, opening a new connection lies in the nature of the technique. You cannot really prevent that (but notice that the network [can optimize this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)). However, imho the focus of the article was on the flaw that you were going to have a huge lot of requests if they are immediately responded to by the server ("steady" polling). You can counter this flaw by using [long polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_polling#Long_polling) (changing how the server treats poll requests):

> Long polling addresses the weakness of traditional polling by keeping
>   the connection to your server open. Keeping the connection to the
>   server open eliminates the travel time from client to server and thus,
>   significantly reduces the issues surrounding network latency.